# Jasperserver and oracle autonomous database

Tags: oracle, jasperserver, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to connect jasperserver to oracle autonomous database (OADB), but with no success. I have successfully configured OADB access from jaspersoft studio by following this tutorial (https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/adw-conn-tibco-jaspersoft.pdf). I also have access to the target OADB from sqlplus on the same server where jasperserver is installed. I tried to configure access for jasperserver similarly to the instructions for jaspersoft studio, also for configuration I used the recommendations from this [JDBC Thin Connections with Wallets (mTLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa%20/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-BE543CFD-6FB4-4C5B-A2EA-9638EC30900D) tutorial. I'm trying to create a connection to the OADB using the jasperserver web interface, but it doesn't seem to accept the format of the string that contains the wallet path [(err example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoDCy.png).
Is it even possible to connect jasperserver to oracle autonomous database at the moment? Please help if someone faced a similar task. I would be grateful for any help.
My software environment:
Jasperserver Community Edition 7.8
OS: Oracle-Linux-7.9-2021.08.27-0
Java: openjdk 11.0.12
Oracle driver: ojdbc8

Comment: read this , perhaps it can help https://community.tibco.com/questions/connectivity-tibco-jaspersoft-studio-professional-oracle-autonomous-database

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Thanks for trying to help, but the topic at the link discusses connecting jaspersoft studio - it's an editor for creating reports. I connected it successfully. My problem is related to jasperreport server - it is an http server for receiving reports from rest api. Unfortunately, for it, I did not find any instructions for connecting to oracle autonomous database or even confirmation it is possible.

Comment: you are right. did you create the data adapter and it connects without issues ? I mean, following the instructions of https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/adw-conn-tibco-jaspersoft.pdf)

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yes, jaspersoft studio connects without problems

Comment: can you put in plain text the string you are using for the URL ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez do you mean try to enter the connection string directly into the jasperserver configuration file bypassing the web interface?

Comment: I mean that your picture shows `dbc` when it should be `jdbc`. Also be sure that the tnsnames.ora file is located in the wallet directory with the same alias you use in the URL string

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yes, you are right. Probably during one of the attempts I made a mistake in the connection string. I now have a successful cloud connection. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome. 4 eyes see better than 2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

At this link you will see pre-requisites:

[JDBC Thin Connections with Wallets (mTLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-EBBB5D6B-118D-48BD-8D68-A3954EC92D2B)

on section 3. tells about the JDK version you must use when connecting with this JDBC.

AND Per link:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/821941/how-can-i-tell-jaspersoft-studio-use-my-current-java-version-instead-bundled-one

Edit your Jaspersoft Studio.ini and remove the lines that read:

-vm

features/jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u151/jre/bin

This will cause jaspersoftstudio to use the JDK you have installed in your computer (not the one that jaspersoft studio has "embedded"); so make sure your computer has at least jdk "1.8.0_171"

Answer (score 0):

Force Tibco Jaspersoft to ignore the embedded (shipped) JDK and use the JDK installed in
Step 2, above
Edit the file “Jaspsersoft Studio Professional.ini” and remove the line
identifying the VM. This will be similar to:
-vm
features/jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u151/jre
/bin